# Live Data Returning In OnCnangeMethod My HomeFragment

Tags: android, retrofit, rest, android-mvvm

i am new to mvvm . i want use result of api call in more than one fragment. please help me sort out the issue

HomeViewModel code is

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MediatorLiveData<PatientsModel> mPatients=new MediatorLiveData<>();

    public void callMemberApi() {
        Retrofit retrofit= RetrofitInstance.getRetroClient();
        WebApi webApi=retrofit.create(WebApi.class);
        Call<PatientsModel> call=webApi.getPatients(SharedPrefs.getString(Constants.TOKEN));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PatientsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PatientsModel> call, Response<PatientsModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    mPatients.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PatientsModel> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }

    public LiveData<PatientsModel> getPatients() {
        return mPatients;
    }

}
```

Code in my fragment is

```
private void observeData() {
        viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        viewModel.callMemberApi();
        viewModel.getPatients().observe(getActivity(),new Observer<PatientsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PatientsModel patientsModel) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, patientsModel.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setPatientsAdapter(patientsModel);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What a problem?

Comment: getting null in onChageMethod

Comment: What do you mean with onChangeMethod? What exactly is coming null?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MutableLiveData<PatientsModel>` expect from `MediatorLiveData<PatientsModel>` in your `HomeViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Use **MutableLiveData** instead of MediatorLiveData

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

 private MutableLiveData<PatientsModel> mPatients=new MutableLiveData<>();

 public void callMemberApi() {
    Retrofit retrofit= RetrofitInstance.getRetroClient();
    WebApi webApi=retrofit.create(WebApi.class);
    Call<PatientsModel> call=webApi.getPatients(SharedPrefs.getString(Constants.TOKEN));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PatientsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PatientsModel> call, Response<PatientsModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                mPatients.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PatientsModel> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}

 public LiveData<PatientsModel> getPatients() {
    return mPatients;
 }
}
```

In fragment, check null

```
private void observeData() {
    viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    viewModel.callMemberApi();
    viewModel.getPatients().observe(getActivity(),new Observer<PatientsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(PatientsModel patientsModel) {
           if(paitentsModel != null){
            Toast.makeText(activity, patientsModel.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setPatientsAdapter(patientsModel);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i use it but nothing  changed

Comment: What nothing changed? What's the issue?

Comment: getting null again

Comment: Then it must be coming from the api. Debug and check api response.

Answer (score 0):

One point to remember about live data is that their default value is null for the object type.

```
private MutableLiveData<PatientsModel> mPatients=new MutableLiveData<>();
```

Now `mPatients` has value null until `mPatients.setValue(response.body());` called.
Since you called observe upon the live data just after calling the API, the observer would observe value immediately but the response depends upon some variables like the speed of network and server latency. Hence you get a null value.

So to handle this situation,

```
viewModel.getPatients().observe(getActivity(),new Observer<PatientsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PatientsModel patientsModel) {
                   if(patientsModel!=null){
                      Toast.makeText(activity, patientsModel.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      setPatientsAdapter(patientsModel);
                   }
            }
        });
```